# udev rule for usb device not working

Tags: linux, rules, udev

sadly my udev rule won't work - I'm trying to make a symlink for a specific USB device. here the info about the device:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d# udevadm info --query=all --attribute-walk --name=/dev/ttyUSB1

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format. A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.5/1-1.3.5.2/1-1.3.5.2:1.0/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.5/1-1.3.5.2/1-1.3.5.2:1.0/ttyUSB1':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="cp210x"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.5/1-1.3.5.2/1-1.3.5.2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3.5.2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="cp210x"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="CP2104 USB to UART Bridge Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.5/1-1.3.5.2':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3.5.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3.5.2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="12"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="200mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="006311F9"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="15"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Silicon Labs"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="CP2104 USB to UART Bridge Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.5':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3.5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3.5"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0835"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="9"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0106"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="51"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Action Star"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="8500"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0835"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0106"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="70"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Action Star"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="8500"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="63"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9514"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0312"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="bcm2708_usb"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="26"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.12.29+ dwc_otg_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb':
    KERNELS=="bcm2708_usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"
    ATTRS{hnp}=="HstNegScs = 0x0"
    ATTRS{srp}=="SesReqScs = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regvalue}=="invalid offset"
    ATTRS{hsic_connect}=="HSIC Connect = 0x1"
    ATTRS{guid}=="GUID = 0x2708a000"
    ATTRS{mode}=="Mode = 0x1"
    ATTRS{srpcapable}=="SRPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regdump}=="Register Dump"
    ATTRS{gpvndctl}=="GPVNDCTL = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{ggpio}=="GGPIO = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{hprt0}=="HPRT0 = 0x00001005"
    ATTRS{wr_reg_test}=="Time to write GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 360 msecs (36 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{hcd_frrem}=="HCD Dump Frame Remaining"
    ATTRS{mode_ch_tim_en}=="Mode Change Ready Timer Enable = 0x0"
    ATTRS{gnptxfsiz}=="GNPTXFSIZ = 0x01000306"
    ATTRS{remote_wakeup}=="Remote Wakeup Sig = 0 Enabled = 0 LPM Remote Wakeup = 0"
    ATTRS{busconnected}=="Bus Connected = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hcddump}=="HCD Dump"
    ATTRS{gotgctl}=="GOTGCTL = 0x001c0001"
    ATTRS{spramdump}=="SPRAM Dump"
    ATTRS{grxfsiz}=="GRXFSIZ = 0x00000306"
    ATTRS{gsnpsid}=="GSNPSID = 0x4f54280a"
    ATTRS{gusbcfg}=="GUSBCFG = 0x00001700"
    ATTRS{hptxfsiz}=="HPTXFSIZ = 0x02000406"
    ATTRS{devspeed}=="Device Speed = 0x0"
    ATTRS{fr_interval}=="Frame Interval = 0x1d4c"
    ATTRS{rem_wakeup_pwrdn}==""
    ATTRS{bussuspend}=="Bus Suspend = 0x0"
    ATTRS{buspower}=="Bus Power = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hnpcapable}=="HNPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{rd_reg_test}=="Time to read GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 1170 msecs (117 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{enumspeed}=="Device Enumeration Speed = 0x1"
    ATTRS{inv_sel_hsic}=="Invert Select HSIC = 0x0"
    ATTRS{regoffset}=="0xffffffff"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

here my udev rule:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules
KERNEL=="ttyUSB?", ATTRS{serial}=="006311F9", SYMLINK+="relais_card"
```

sadly it's not working:

```
 udevadm test /dev/ttyUSB1
run_command: calling: test
adm_test: version 175
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program,
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/10-local-rpi.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/42-qemu-usb.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-fuse.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-2.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/run/udev/rules.d/61-dev-root-link.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules' as rules file
add_rule: IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id', replacing /lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules:78
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/70-udev-acl.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-cd-aliases-generator.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-dell.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-fujitsu.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-gateway.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-ibm.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-lenovo.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-toshiba.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules' as rules file
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules' as rules file
udev_rules_new: rules use 225780 bytes tokens (18815 * 12 bytes), 30112 bytes buffer
udev_rules_new: temporary index used 55560 bytes (2778 * 20 bytes)
unable to open device '/sys/dev/ttyUSB1'
```

do you have any clue where my problem could be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply restarting the udev process didn't do any changes and also the test command didn't match the rules. A reboot however made the changes correctly, so the fix was a simple reboot

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that you have printed the info of `/dev/ttyUSB1`

Wheareas the error claims to not be able to open the `/sys/dev/ttyUSB1` ?

---

After you claify what is what then I would recommend firstly to check if there is already any process which is holding your device opened.

You can do that probably with

`sudo lsof | grep (your device name here)`